# What is the big-O complexity of an algorithm that evaluates all unique pairs of a list's items?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

If I have a function that evaluates every pair of elements in a list, including pairs of an element with itself and with elements it has previously been evaluated against, the complexity of that function is, obviously, $O(n^2)$:

```
for (let i=0; i < n; i++) {
  for (let j=0; j < n; j++) {
    // this line will be executed n * n times
    operate(l[i], l[j]);
  }
}
```

However, if I have a variant of that loop that only considers pairs of elements  that *have not yet been compared*, is the complexity of *that* function *still* $O(n^2)$?

```
for (let i=0; i < n; i++) {
  for (let j=i+1; j < n; j++) {
    // this line will be executed (n * n-1) / 2 times?
    operate(l[i], l[j]);
  }
}
```

There are a few things about this that I still don't understand:

- How can we calculate that the furthering reduction in `j` will divide the operations by 2? (I'm only inferring the $/2$ because I know that matchup tables have half the table redundant; I wouldn't know how to evaluate the reduction if, say, only even indices were compared against odd indices.)
- Why doesn't that $/2$ matter? How do we determine the asymptote? How does $(n * (n-1)) / 2$ get reduced to $O(n^2)$? Are we just removing terms in reverse order of operations, by picking which one incorporates higher-order operations on variables (so $(n * (n-1)) / 2$ becomes $(n * (n-1))$, which becomes $(n * n)$)?
- How does this generalize for $x$-tuples? If we're comparing triplets, is the complexity $O(n^3)$? Does it go up as $O(n^x)$? Is the non-asymptotic complexity still divided by 2 for orders of 3 or more? Would the numerator be $(n * (n-1) * (n-2))$? How would that be expressed generally for orders of $x$ (would it look like $(n * (n - 1) * ... * (n - (x - 1) ))$?)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a system behind the magic of algorithm analysis?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis)

Comment: 1) $O$ is an *upper* bound, so if you do *less*, then yea, the upper bound carries over. 2) I agree with @Evil's comment; you need to go at this in a structured way, not guessing.

Comment: @Raphael Okay, cool. Maybe, since this is a *Q & A* site, I could get some answers that could actually *help me* to go at this in such a structured way? Maybe described in simpler terms, more accessible to someone *who is struggling with this question* because they *do not have a deep background in computer science*, than a ten-page essay describing the problem as $\qquad\displaystyle \mathbb{E}[C_{\text{swaps}}] = \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{A} \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} \sum_{j=0}^{n-i-2} C_{5,9}(A^{(i,j)})$?

Comment: There are plenty of [tag:algorithm-analysis+loops] questions around you can check out for examples. I also think that if you actually tried and read the reference question, you'd have found what you need (namely how to translate loops into sums). Note that even on Q&A sites, some prior knowledge and own effort can be expected. (This is *not* a deep question.)